# Python - from twython import Twython "Invalid Syntax"

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, twython

I'm trying to set up the twitter api Twython on a Raspberry Pi, but keep getting an invalid syntax error after the first line. I can run this without error in a separate Ubuntu machine so maybe it's related to the install of twython itself. I've searched on the forum and most of the errors have been due to import errors. Not sure what's going on here with this code. I used pip to install twython using the command sudo pip install twython.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from twython import Twython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twython/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .api import Twython
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twython/api.py", line 15, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa, rsa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py", line 8, in <module>
    from fractions import gcd
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/fractions.py", line 7, in <module>
    from decimal import Decimal
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 140, in <module>
    import numbers as _numbers
  File "numbers.py", line 1
    Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You appear to have a `numbers.py` file around that is shadowing a file in Python's library.   Furthermore, it's not a syntactically valid Python file - looks like it might be a copy-and-paste of a Python interpreter session.  Rename or remove it.

Comment: I had a seperate file in the home directory named "numbers.py" which I deleted and the twython import worked after the delete. Thanks!